# Ajax and php Question

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Finally got my domain checker working. Now the question is I have a form (search-domains) when user types and submits at the moment it passes the query to process.php and that out puts:
echo "$Domain is/isn't available"

What I want is this to return on my results page (the results page also has a search form on it so if someone searches there it would display on same page). At the moment when user clicks it passes http://example.com/process.php?domain=domain.com(etc...).

What i think i need is Ajax to pull this url before it goes to process.php then ajax runs the query process sends result back to ajax an it outputs on the results page. Also I have another php script which displays the domain with different tlds and displays id they are available or not. So i also need ajax to run this and display aswell.

I am very new to ajax but looking for tutorials but most of them are for displaying success messages after contact forms and the like. If someone could point me in the right direction id much appreciate it.

EDIT

This is what i have but itsd still re-directing me to process.php

HTML

```
<form method="get" id="form">
   <input type="text" class="searchdomains" onclick="if (this.value =='Domain Name Search...'){this.value=''}" value="Domain Name Search..." name="domain" id="search-domain-input">
   <input type="image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/inc/img/btn_up_search.png" class="search" name="Search" id="Submit">
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$.ajax(
 {
  type: 'GET',
  url : "http://example.com/process.php?domain=",
   // here you pass js object in convention: { 'query_string' : 'its value' }
  data : { 'domain' : $('#search-domain-input').val() },
  success: function (data) {


    $("#results").html(data);
  }
 }

);
```

PHP

```
if(isset($avail)){
   echo '<p>'.$avail.' is available to be registered</p>'
} else {
   echo '<p>'.$avail.' is taken register with us for price</p>'
}
```

Thanks
Joe

Comment: @Brian yeah must state i am new to it :)

Answer (score 0):

in jquery (http://jquery.com/) you can make ajax requests by using the function :

```
$.ajax(
 {
  url : "url to fetch",
  success: function (data) {
    // data is variable that is returned from server as HTML by default, or you can use JSON format 

    $("#content").html(data);
  }
 }

);
```

If you dont want to use jquery javascript library, you need to create xmlhttprequest object and make helper functions for it, which i do not recommend, since jquery can be used for more stuff than just ajax calls.

EDIT :

@comment

simply create process.php where you will accept "domain" as query string - which will check if the domain exists, if not it should echo `<p>'$result.'is/isn't available</p>`, than in $.ajax({...}); pass that url and "data" will be available to you.

To pass GET params with $.ajax() you can use the following setting:

```
$.ajax(
 {
  type: 'GET',
  url : "url to fetch",
   // here you pass js object in convention: { 'query_string' : 'its value' }
  data : { 'domain' : $('#domain_name_input_field').val() },
  success: function (data) {
    // data is variable that is returned from server as HTML by default, or you can use JSON format 

    $("#content").html(data);
  }
 }

);
```

Comment: so i would put url:"example.com/process.php?domain=", how would i pass the input from the form to after the domain= part. Now the content bit to be passed would i just say echo '<p>'$result.'is/isn't available</p>' in process.php. is that right or am i missing something. :)